# Blank space on right side of layout

Tags: html, css, firefox, fancybox, 960.gs

Just finished building a site for my company at http://awesome.redfishbluefishmedia.com, and I'm noticing a strange issue.

ONLY when your browser starts out about 1000px wide, I'm seeing blank space on the right side of the page (this is an issue because iPhone shows it at about that size, and it's quite noticeable on iPhone when loading the home page for the first time, as there's a Fancybox popup which comes up once on the home page). You can scroll farther than you should be able to essentially.

It's a strip down the side, and having searched through the elements, I can't find any that seem to be pushing it over (except possibly the slider on the home page, but this issue is present on other pages as well).

Can anyone help? Can't figure it out, and I feel like this has to be something obvious.

Using the 960.gs grid to standardize my layout.

UPDATE: I added this...

```
body, html {
     overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

and that fixed my issue, I think, but I still have no idea why I was seeing that scroll issue; if anyone can enlighten, you'd still be much appreciated.

Comment: I took out the `overflow-x: hidden` rule and still don't see a white line. Did you observe this behaviour in a desktop browser? I'm using Chrome 19 OSX

Comment: Wait I see what you mean, I'll get back to you. Intriguing!

Comment: Interesting. That could be what's happening (the clearfix thing), although the posts that I'm seeing say that this may result in excess vertical spacing, rather than excess horizontal spacing (and I'm not seeing any specific elements which flow outside the body or html with the overflow-x rule removed.

Comment: @MusikAnimal, yes, I initially thought it was just iPhone (that's where it's most apparent), but I'm seeing it in all browsers.

Comment: Strangely, on Firefox 13 OSX, with the `overflow-x: hidden` rule, you see a second vertical scrollbar...? I got rid of the rule and it disappeared. [see image](http://imgur.com/WC3zg)

Comment: Whoa. You're correct. I have no idea what would cause that (never seen this particular issue before). Still less bad than the initial issue, but it would seem my solution needs some fixing as well.

Comment: Double scrollbars seem to be fixed by adding body, html {height:100%;}

Answer (score 0):

Hi now just remove `overflow-x: hidden` and add `min-width` in your `body` and `html` tag as like this

```
body, html {
    min-width: 1207px; // add this line 
    overflow-x: hidden; // remove this line 
}
```

Comment: This solution has the unfortunate effect of un-centering the layout.